# Escape "(" in N string oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, escaping

I am trying to understand why in a string in oracle sql statement, where i have something like this "*%abc (Weiter%*" i get no result, whereas if i use this string "*%abc (%*" i do get results. From what i can see is that "(W" is the issue here. (the element with "Weiter" exists)
Does anyone know how to proceed next?
Thank you for your time either way.

I cannot give the exact sql, but this is a part of it:

```
// this brings nothing:
SELECT * FROM tabel_name where name = N'Sunny / Day (Weather)'

// this brings 1 result expected with column value "Sunny / Day (Weather)":
SELECT name FROM tabel_name where id = 3456 

// this brings 1 result with column value "Sunny / Day (Weather)":
SELECT * FROM tabel_name where name like N'%Sunny / Day (%' 

// this does not bring any result:
SELECT * FROM tabel_name where name like N'%Sunny / Day (W%'
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste the Sunny / Day (W and then add the %?  Perhaps the W is some sort of special character and not infact a capital W.  You may want to UPPER your query as well incase case sensitivity is a problem.  Sample Escape: like '%\_io\_%' ESCAPE '\';

Comment: Lets try that sample again: seems to have dropped the \ when I pasted like '%\\_io\\_%' ESCAPE '\';  lol I had to escape the \ when posting :D

Comment: I can see from here [link](http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions--Regexp-Cheat-Sheet_856.htm) that \W, \w are special characters. But dont really understand why "(W" should be a problem. The "Sunny / Day (W...." I copied it from previous select with the id condition.

Comment: @GabrielaRadu: `\w` is only a special character for regular expressions, not for the `LIKE` operator. Why do you use the `N` prefix? Did you try without?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what happened when I attempted to reproduce your problem.  I'm using Oracle 11g XE beta here:

```
SQL> create table ntest (name nvarchar2(2000));

Table created.

SQL> insert into ntest (name) values (N'Sunny / Day (Weather)');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select name from ntest where name like N'%Sunny / Day (%';

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sunny / Day (Weather)

SQL> select name from ntest where name like N'%Sunny / Day (W%';

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sunny / Day (Weather)
```

I can't help but conclude that the problem is with your data.  Perhaps it has some funny characters in it, such as a [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) or a [soft hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) between the `(` and the `W`?

Comment: Or that `name` is not `nvarchar2` but `varchar`, perhaps.

Comment: @ypercube: I tried using a table with a `varchar2` column instead of `nvarchar2` and got the same result.

Comment: Then I guess you are right. Either the data is not what the OP thinks or there is another problem (he states that he is NOT giving the full query)

Comment: I am looking at the query and space in the string again. you might be right.

Comment: i had a type in the query.Couldn't see it at first, after looking more carefull i saw it. Thx. stupid mistake on my side :)